# Difference of matrix inverses into a product

Tags: matrices

I came accross the following equality 
$$ (B-zI)^{-1}-(B+\tau qq^*-zI)^{-1}=\tau(B-zI)^{-1}qq^*(B+\tau qq^*-zI)^{-1} $$
Here, $z=u+iv \in \mathbb{C^+}$, $A$ is a $N\times N$ matrices, $B$ is $N\times N$ Hermitian, $\tau\in \mathbb{R}$, $q\in \mathbb{C}^N$.

Why is the above equility hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let 
$$A=(B-zI)^{-1}-(B+\tau qq^*-zI)^{-1}$$

Calculate
$$(B-zI)A(B+\tau qq^*-zI)$$

Comment: Thank you.  That evaluates to $\tau qq^*$, and the equility follows.